# Ionic Cordova camera black screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Our app is used ionic and cordova camera plugin. Sometimes the camera screen will become black screen. After shutdown the app , the camera screen will recover to normal. And this problem is not always occurred. It only occurred on some devices in sometime.

The run-time environment of  our app are below:
1. OS : iOS 10.2
2.Ionic : 1.3.2
3. Cordova-iOS: 4.3.1
4.Cordova-Camera-plugin:2.3.0

Could you tell us what's the possible reasons for this black screen issue.

Comment: We have confirmed that the app has the camera access priv. And user can take photo at first time, when take the next picture the camera become black screen.

Comment: I think the problem is your phone memory, this happens in native apps sometimes too, it's not because of the plugin, but because of the native component the plugin uses

Comment: i encounter the same problem now, did u find the way to solve it?

Comment: Really, there are not found any solution yet?